# MYSQL Date and Java Date

Tags: java, mysql, sql, resultset

i store the current date with the sql code `NOW()`

After that i have a JAVA application that get that information from database.
I use a ResultSet to get that information.

```
data.setDate(rs.getDate("data"));
```

Well this works but if i make a println of that i would get something like:

```
2014-01-27T10:10:10Z
```

So i would like to remove the T and Z letters when printing the date and sometimes i get the time like this and i don't know why:

```
00:00:00Z
```

Thanks

Comment: Use Java [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format your date get from database in format you required.

Comment: Searching StackOverflow for "java date format" will find many answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use Simple date formatter, like:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");// or any date format you want
System.out.println(sdf.format(rs.getDate("data")));
```